# Oracle-Why Aggregation function is not working on TO_NUMBER?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to sum of amounts in a query. When I run query-1 , it works.

query-1:

```
SELECT T2.OUTLET_ID,(((TO_NUMBER(T2.ITEM_CTN)*TO_NUMBER(T4.FACTOR))+TO_NUMBER(T2.ITEM_QTY))*TO_NUMBER(T2.OUT_PRICE))
FROM T_ORDER_DETAIL T2 , 
     T_ITEM T4
WHERE T2.SR_ID=109299 AND T2.ENTRY_DATE=TO_DATE( '11/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

[image: query-1]

But when I run query-2, it works error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

query-2:

```
SELECT T2.OUTLET_ID,SUM((((TO_NUMBER(T2.ITEM_CTN)*TO_NUMBER(T4.FACTOR))+TO_NUMBER(T2.ITEM_QTY))*TO_NUMBER(T2.OUT_PRICE)))
FROM T_ORDER_DETAIL T2 , 
     T_ITEM T4
WHERE T2.SR_ID=109299 AND T2.ENTRY_DATE=TO_DATE( '11/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')
GROUP BY T2.OUTLET_ID;
```

[image: query-2]

Wheres the problem?

Comment: Toad is not querying the full result, you're only seeing the top X rows. The error occurs later. When you aggregate, more source rows are processed to produce same number of rows, so it'll get to the bad row, i.e. the row where one of your 4 columns do not contain a valid number. --- You should ask yourself: Why are numbers stored in text columns? Smells of a bad data model.

Comment: Why are you storing numeric values as strings?  That is an original sin, which leads to messy and error-prone SQL statements.

Comment: I didn't do it dear. It's a team project. My reporting boss did this. and now I can not change this.I have not got this right.so,So,what should I do plz tell me.

Comment: If you can't fix the data type - and you should at least try to raise it with your team/boss - you have to find and fix the value that cannot be converted from a string to a number. Well, you'll need to do that even if you *do* end up fixing the data type.